# Move background according to viewport centered website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a websit ethat is centered with the good old container technique with a margin of 0 auto but I want my background to folow my main div is there a way to achieve that? I want my bacground to always be 540px right of my centered div.

Comment: Could you give us a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Align the background image using

```
background-position: 50% 0px;
```

and give the image itself an appropriate padding on the left side (add transparent pixels)

Comment: Oh wait a minute... that could as well be very wrong. Very hard to imagine background positioning without seeing in a browser. Can you post your problem to jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VahAf/1/ 
Basically I want my background to always be where it is if window is 920px